# String.Format is not working properly

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have below code :

```
private string Do2Decimal(string value)
{
    return String.Format("{0:0.##}", value);
}
```

Here I am passing string value as **16.32222**.
What I know is, above code should format my value to 16.32.
But it is showing output value as **16.32222**.

What mistake I am doing here??

Update : 
I have values in string format that is : "16.32222".
Sorry forgot to mention before.

Comment: Since you are passing in a string it will not be formatted as a number. either pass a float or double or decimal or convert.parse the string to work as a number..

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Because you are **passing it a string value**. The formatting would work for floating point numbers / decimals. Just parse the number to either decimal / double type depending on your requirement like:

```
String.Format("{0:0.##}", decimal.Parse(value));
```

You can also use [`decimal.TryParse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.decimal.tryparse%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) *(or TryParse)* family method for safer parsing. You can also modify your method to receive decimal/double type parameter and then apply the formatting. It would convey a better intent, IMO.

If your string has `.` as [NumberDecimalSeparator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.numberformatinfo.numberdecimalseparator.aspx)  and your culture doesn't support `.` as NumberDecimalSeparator then you can pass `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` while parsing like:

```
string value = "16.322222";
string formattedString = String.Format("{0:0.##}", decimal.Parse(value, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
```

Comment: Might be worth noting that if the `value` is a product of `num.ToString()`, its much safer to just pass in the number (OP doesn't actually state they are using the Decimal type, just requires a number to 2dp)

Comment: Hi i have values in string that is : "16.32222". I tried decimal.parse but it doesnt work for me.

Comment: don't forget about CultureInfo notion. Fundamental for floating point number parse from arbitrary strings.

Comment: @Ajay, may be you are on a culture which requires a different character for fraction point. You can use `decimal.Parse(value, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);`

Comment: @Habib Just for curiosity I am asking this. If i have string as 0 that is "0", then can i display output as 0.00 using this code??

Comment: @Ajay, no. You will need `0.00` instead of `0.##`, Your code has `#` which is for optional number.

Answer (score -2):

**Try this**

```
String.Format("{0:0.00}", decimal.Parse(value));
```

to get two degit value after point.